# LEAP YEAR validate input for 2104, 2000, 2100, 2001 using JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

Find if a year is a leap year or not using the if...else statements described above. Validate your program for the following input: 2104 (true), 2100 (false), 2000 (true), 2001 (false). Hint: A leap year is evenly divisible by 4; however, if a year is evenly divided by 100, it is not a leap year, unless the year is also evenly divisible by 400.

Hi I see two alternative solutions. But only one approach gives solution and the other condition fails. Can anyone help why?

Success output

```js
function leapYear3(year) {
  if ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) {
    console.log('TRUE');
  } else if (year % 400 == 0) {
    console.log('TRUE');
  } else {
    console.log('FALSE');
  }
}
console.log(leapYear3(2104)); // True
console.log(leapYear3(2000)); // True
console.log(leapYear3(2100)); // False
console.log(leapYear3(2001)); // False

//Failing : Output
function leapYear3(year) {
  if (year % 4 == 0) {
    console.log('TRUE');
  } else if ((year % 400 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) {
    console.log('TRUE');
  } else {
    console.log('FALSE');
  }
}

console.log(leapYear3(2104)); // True
console.log(leapYear3(2000)); // True
console.log(leapYear3(2100)); // True
console.log(leapYear3(2001)); // False
```

Why this condition is not right 
`((year % 400 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0))` while this code below is right
 `((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0))`

Comment: for which value it is not right?

Comment: The problem is that if you do `year % 4 == 0` before anything else it will evaluate to true for 2100 before it even checks `year % 100 != 0`.

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan Hi Syed 

for 2100 it is showing TRUE, supposed be FALSE

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze oh I get it now. Thanks for the response kevin.

Comment: OT a better architecture would be to not use console.log to directly write the answer, but to return a true/false value from the function. Then print TRUE or FALSE from the code that calls it

Answer (score 1):

In the second function, your first condition is only "divisible by 4":

```
if (year % 4 == 0)
```

so 2100 is a leap year - as wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

Because 2100 % 4 == 0 it consoles 0

```js
function leapYear3(year) {
  if (year % 4 == 0) { //2100 % 4 = 0 the codition is true here so it doesnot go in the else if loop
    console.log('TRUE');
  } else if ((year % 400 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) {
    console.log('TRUE');
  } else {
    console.log('FALSE');
  }
}

console.log(leapYear3(2100)); // True
```

Answer (score 0):

This sholud work in all JS implementations:

```
function isLeapYear(year) {
    return new Date(year, 1, 29, 0, 0).getMonth() !== 2;
}
```